# insertNewObject into coreData

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

I am trying to insert an NSData object into CoreData, So I have had to add everything to my application after the fact because I never started it with coredata selected. thats okay though as I have started a new project and copied all of the appropriate code across to get it all set up.

From there I am now trying to set up the insertNewObject method. However this is giving me some issues.

I am first of all trying to pass it some NSData from another method like this

```
[self insertNewObject:myData];
```

and then I am using the insertNewObject method like this

```
- (void)insertNewObject:(id)sender
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchRequest] entity];
    NSManagedObject *newManagedObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Entity" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    // If appropriate, configure the new managed object.
    // Normally you should use accessor methods, but using KVC here avoids the need to add a custom class to the template.
    [newManagedObject setValue:sender forKey:@"manufacturers"]; //not sure if this is correct, but sender has myData, and @"manufactures" is the attribute of my entity.

    // Save the context.
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. 
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }
}
```

From here what happens is that when the thread gets too the third line "NSManagedObject *newManagedObject..." The application crashes and I get this error

```
> 2012-04-27 11:18:21.579 thecode[1452:fb03] *** Terminating app due to
> uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason:
> '+entityForName: could not locate an NSManagedObjectModel for entity
> name 'Entity''
> *** First throw call stack: (0x14b5022 0x1952cd6 0x61d47 0xa8102 0x1a595 0x199a4 0x18b99 0x15097 0x1136a49 0x1134e84 0x1135ea7
> 0x1134e3f 0x1134fc5 0x1079f5a 0x1c02a39 0x1ccf596 0x1bf9120 0x1ccf117
> 0x1bf8fbf 0x148994f 0x13ecb43 0x13ec424 0x13ebd84 0x13ebc9b 0x215b7d8
> 0x215b88a 0x733626 0x762d 0x1c75 0x1) terminate called throwing an
> exception
```

I have set up the entity and attribute needed for this inside my xcdatamodeld

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please have a look here. It may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10082491/managedobjectcontext-is-nil/10100170#10100170

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of your CoreData model but i guess you don't have a entity with the name "Entity" so this might cause the crash as you are trying to insert a new entity with name "Entity" here:

```
[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Entity" inManagedObjectContext:context];
```

As you are fetching an entity description one line above but never using it later on, i guess you are trying to insert this entity. So what you have to do is basically:

```
    [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:entity.name inManagedObjectContext:context];
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am still getting the same error, so I Logged entity to see what the value its holding and all i get back is **null** so not sure whats going on there. all my core data model is, is one entity called Manu with an attribute called Balls :)

Comment: maybe you can try: NSManagedObject *newManagedObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Manu" inManagedObjectContext:context];
this should give you a valid CoreData object.

Comment: unfortunately not. I am thinking maybe My class cannot see my object model... if I was getting null back, and even if i hard cord it and still cannot see it then there must be something that I have maybe missed in the application delegate or something... ?

Answer (score 1):

Also check that your managedObjectContext is not nil. You'll get exactly this error when it is. When you instantiated the fetchedResultsController you associated an NSManagedObjectContext with it. Where did you get that context from?

If this is in a view controller that you've drilled down into, be sure you're passing the managedObjectContext from the app delegate into each subsequent controller so that they all have access to it. You can then pass it to the fetchedResultsController correctly.

Comment: its most defiantly nil, I have tryied to log it to the console.. I am not sure where I am instantiating it i think that might be in the app delegate, I have to have a look. But I am trying to use this in a nsobject class. so nothing to do with views etc.. Thank you for the reply, I was starting to think i was going to have to scrap my whole project and start again.

Comment: I declare a ** NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;** object in the header and then synthesize it in the .m file.. but when I synthesize it I do this

**@synthesize managedObjectContext = __managedObjectContext;** where __managedObjectContext I think is being declared in my app delegate...

Comment: You're talking about on the object? If I understand you correctly, you still need to pass the managedObjectConext to the object from the app delegate or wherever else you're creating it. Something like myObject.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext if you're handling it inside the app delegate

Comment: cool, Ill give it ago now/over the weekend and let you know how I got.. I kind of understand you but I I dont know where or how to do this. my brain is complete mush atm.

Comment: just woundering isn't this what I am doing in my nsobject class when I use **synthesize managedObjectContext = __managedObjectContext;** where the app delegate creates and initalizes **__managedObjectContext**

Comment: All your doing with the property and synthesize code is declaring an instance variable on the object and creating the getters and setters for it. This isn't like a global variable that has now been connected to the variable with the same name on the app delegate.